# How to store all form values from slider in objects, array or json with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on custom slider form in bootstrap and jQuery, and I am able to get form field values on click on radio button, button etc. My problem is I want to store all these values in series like JavaScript objects, array or JSON etc to process all the info, but I'm unable to store these values in series to get one person's information from these fields.

My HTML code is:

```
      <div id="carousel-personal-loan" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row per-loan-gender">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row male_or_female">
                        <div class="quote-title" msg="Please select your gender">My gender<span class="label label-danger"></span></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <label>
                                <img src="1.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Male</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <label>
                                <img src="2.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Female</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row nxt-prev-btn">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-slide">Next</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="row per-loan-city">
          <div class="quote-title" msg="Where do you live currently?">Where do you live currently?<span class="label label-danger"></span></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="3.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hyderabad" value="hyderabad" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Hyderabad</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="4.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="chennai" value="chennai" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Chennai</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="5.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="bangalore" value="bangalore" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Bangalore</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="6.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hosur" value="hosur" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Hosur</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>
                        <img src="7" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="other_city" value="other city" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Other City</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row nxt-prev-btn">
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-slide">Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-slide">Next</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="item" id="SalOrSelf">
          <div class="row per-loan-sources">
            <div class="quote-title" msg="Are You">Are You<span class="label label-danger"></span></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row sal_or_self">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <label>
                                <img src="8.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="salorself" id="salaried" value="salaried" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Salaried</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <label>
                                <img src="9.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="salorself" id="selfemp" value="selfemp" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Self-employed</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row nxt-prev-btn">
                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-slide">Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-slide">Next</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="salcont"></div>
      </div>
<!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

My jQuery and object create code is:

```
jQuery(".active input[type=radio]" ).live( "click", function() {
        var getAllValues = jQuery(this).val();
        alert(getAllValues); //Able to get all the values here when click on fields in slider
        var getQuote = { "maleOrFemale":"MaleOrFemale", "currentCity":"YourCity", "Profession":"salOrSelf" };
            getQuote.maleOrFemale = getAllValues; //Not be able to Modify value in above getQuote Object
            getQuote.currentCity = getAllValues;  //Not be able to Modify value in above getQuote Object
            getQuote.Profession = getAllValues;   //Not be able to Modify value in above getQuote Object
            console.log(getQuote); //Not showing proper results as I want to modify all above objects as per form field selection
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .use with [`on()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWx-K4p4PUAhXItY8KHYpYBT8QFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w) instead of `live()` And also use `change`event instead of `click` .Better way to create the object key from [`name(attr('name'))`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv1--sp4PUAhXMP48KHS98CfQQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg) of the input tag

**Working example Updated**

```js
var getQuote = { };
jQuery("input[type=radio] , select").on("change", function() { // select tag was added
$("input[type=radio]:checked ,select").each(function(a){ // selected value  pass with object
  getQuote[$(this).attr('name')] = jQuery(this).val();
})
  console.log(getQuote);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selected">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
</select>
<div id="carousel-personal-loan" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="row per-loan-gender">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="row male_or_female">
            <div class="quote-title" msg="Please select your gender">My gender<span class="label label-danger"></span></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 male">
              <label>
                                <img src="1.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Male</span>
                            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 female">
              <label>
                                <img src="2.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Female</span>
                            </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row nxt-prev-btn">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-slide">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row per-loan-city">
        <div class="quote-title" msg="Where do you live currently?">Where do you live currently?<span class="label label-danger"></span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <label>
                        <img src="3.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hyderabad" value="hyderabad" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Hyderabad</span>
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <label>
                        <img src="4.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="chennai" value="chennai" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Chennai</span>
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <label>
                        <img src="5.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="bangalore" value="bangalore" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Bangalore</span>
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <label>
                        <img src="6.png" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="hosur" value="hosur" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Hosur</span>
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <label>
                        <img src="7" width="130" height="130">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="livecity" id="other_city" value="other city" class="next-slide">
                        </div>
                        <span>Other City</span>
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row nxt-prev-btn">
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-slide">Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-slide">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="SalOrSelf">
      <div class="row per-loan-sources">
        <div class="quote-title" msg="Are You">Are You<span class="label label-danger"></span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="row sal_or_self">
            <div class="col-xs-6 male">
              <label>
                                <img src="8.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="salorself" id="salaried" value="salaried" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Salaried</span>
                            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 female">
              <label>
                                <img src="9.png" />
                                <div>
                                    <input type="radio" name="salorself" id="selfemp" value="selfemp" class="next-slide">
                                </div>
                                <span>Self-employed</span>
                            </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row nxt-prev-btn">
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-slide">Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-slide">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="salcont"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you code is working fine as I have removed $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(a){ and });

Comment: Now my problem is I have also some text and select fields etc, how can I store values of these fields in that object by click on next button, or can I merge objects or something like that?

Comment: @Barjinder You need to store the selected field value also in this object right? see my updated answer .I was added `select` tag fo example same code is enough simple add the `select` with jquery selector .See the updated js code in the snippet

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, as I'm using append to add fields dynamically so I do this with by adding same like code for other appended fields. Now everything working fine and I'm able to store all the values in objects now, thank you for your answer on my question with perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Each time an answer is selected you could append the answer to an object/array?

I would also suggest using the "change" event rather than click event, as it is not necessary to run the code unless the values have been changed.

You could try something like this:

```
var obj = {};

$('.active input[type=radio]').on("change", function(){
    var $this =  $(this), 
        $name = $this.attr("name");
    obj[$name] = $this.val();   
});
```

In doing this, you would get a result that looked something like this:

```
obj = {
    gender: "male",
    livecity: "othercity",
    salorself: "selfemp"
};
```

In doing this, it would also allow people to go back and change their answers if you wanted to allow them to do so.

Comment: Can you please be specific about my code? As I did't understand attr("name") etc.

Comment: The attr("name") will get the name you have given to the group of radio buttons, for example "gender", or "livecity", e.g. <input type='radio' name='gender'>. Doing it this way would also allow people to go back and easily change their answer is the old answer would just get updated.

Comment: your code was also indicating but not as specific as above answer so I take that solution for my site.

Comment: Glad it could help, though not sure how it's less specific.